# How to fix scrolling of iframe in IOS safari

Tags: ios, ipad, html, iframe, scroll

I have a problem related to scrolling of iframe in iPad-Safari.I am developing a web application, which contains some nested iframes and I am not able to scroll content inside the iframe in IOS (safari).

Answer (score 0):

Nested iFrames can be scrolled with two fingers but is not very responsive or user-friendly.

Answer (score 0):

apply this to iframe.

```
overflow:auto;
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code just put the iframe inside a div and use the js code

[github](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/2388015)